# Youtube iframe expects attributes that are not in my typescript definitions

Tags: typescript

Here I try to embed a youtube video:

```
<iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`} frameborder="0" />
```

I get a Typescript error:

```
[ts] Property 'frameborder' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<IframeHTMLAttributes<HTMLIFrameElement>, HTMLIFrameElement>'.
```

If this were a `[tslint]` error I could just disable `tslint` for that row. But unfortunately it is a `[ts]` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute name is supposed to be written in camel case as `frameBorder`; see [the React declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/be662c475da091788139b486a55708f02e2880b6/types/react/index.d.ts#L1447).  React should translate the attribute name to lowercase for you.